# Recovering Jupyter Notebook files after computer crashed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I use Jupyter Notebooks (run through Anaconda) to code in Python. Last week, my computer crashed (not really sure the exact reason), I sent it for repairs and got it back and it has been basically completely reset and now all my apps/files are gone (repair invoice says a "part" was replaced, but not what part).

My question: is there any way to recover my jupyter notebook files or are they completely gone? I've seen instructions to recover accidentally deleted notebooks but not sure if there is a way to recover files after a computer crash. I am using Windows if that helps at all.

If it's not possible to recover these files, what is the best way to back them up in the future? I was under the impression that since jupyter notebooks opened on a web browser, the files would be stored on some sort of cloud, but it appears that is not the case.

Comment: did you look at the .ipynb_checkpoints folder in your notebook directory?

Comment: You can use Google Colab, that's backed up.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure how to access the .ipynb_checkpoints folder..I don't see any checkpoints folder listed under my "Files" page

Comment: A notebook on the hard drive will have been erased like any other file. Were you using a service like OneDrive or Dropbox to backup/store local files? _(repair invoice says a "part" was replaced, but not what part)_ That seems strange, is there any way you could try to get more information? Did they ask you to backup your data before sending the computer for repair?